# Get a list of checked checkboxes that also has a specific data-attribute value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, custom-data-attribute

I have a table of data containing a checkbox that the user can select to either export the record or edit the record. For editing the checkbox has a data attribute that shows whether the specific set of data is editable (based on user-permissions).

I am trying to get a list of the checkbox values where the checkbox is checked AND the data attribute has a value "True".

In my view model I have the field:

```
        public bool ShortageIsEditable {get;set;}
```

This is set in the view model mapper to either true or false depending on the status of the record and the permissions of the user.

In my view I have a table that has the following checkbox with data attribute for each record:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(item.Shortages)
              .Name(string.Format("ShortagesGrid_{0}", item.Id))
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Template(GetViewLink)
                         .Title("View")
                         .Width(38);


                  columns.Template(o => "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selectedRequestId\" " + (o.IsSelected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") + "class=\"myCssCheckAllCheckBox\"  value=\"" + o.ShortageNo + "\"  data-iseditable=\"" + o.ShortageIsEditable + "\"/>")
                         .Width(30);

                  columns.Bound(o => o.ShortageNo)
                         .Title("Shortage #")
                         .Width(120);
```

...

When the user selected some records for edit (checked the checkboxes) and presses the Edit button, the following javascript/JQuery function is executed:

```
    function submitGridSelectedItemsForEdit() {
    $('#gridExportForm').attr('action', '/Requests/Shortage/MultiEditShortages');
    $('#gridExportForm').attr('method', 'GET');


    var chkdlist = $('input[name="selectedRequestId"]:checked');
    var newlist = chkdlist.filter(function (el) {
        return el.data("iseditable") === "True";
    });

    newlist.submit();
```

This will always crash on the line "return el.data("iseditable") === "True";".
I have also tried using the following, but this crashes on submitting the newlist array:

```
    function submitGridSelectedItemsForEdit() {
    $('#gridExportForm').attr('action', '/Requests/Shortage/MultiEditShortages');
    $('#gridExportForm').attr('method', 'GET');


    var chkdlist = $('input[name="selectedRequestId"]:checked');
    var newlist = [];

    for (var chk in chkdlist)
    {
        if (chk.data("isEditable") == true) {
            newlist.push(chk);
        }
    }

    if (newlist.length == 0) {
        alert("Please select at least 1 request to Edit.");
    }
    else {
        newlist.submit();
    }
}
```

What is the easiest way to get the list of objects that is both checked and has a data-attribute value of "True"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`el` in `filter()` callback is the dom element, not a jQuery object. LAso it is not the first argument of the callback it is the second.

So to use jQuery methods you need to wrap `el` in `$()`

```
var newlist = chkdlist.filter(function (_,el) {
    return $(el).data("iseditable") === "True";
});
```

Or filter based on the attribute value as selector

```
var newlist = chkdlist.filter('[data-iseditable="True"]')
```

Comment: I think you will find `el` is the indexer - should be `return $(this).data("iseditable") === "True";`

Comment: And the 2nd would need to be `chkdlist.filter('[data-iseditable="True"]')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will try the 2nd option first.

Comment: Yes!! It works like a charm. Thank you very much for the quick answer!